# Move element over specific horizontal distance to reveal another element with touch event

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

I am looking at simulating an app interface... a list item is swiped to the left to reveal a button thru a touch event. I have seen stuff like swipe.js but it makes you swipe the list item away completely to reveal other item not just moving it over like 100px...

Not sure if this is yet possible with a touch event or not... guidance would be much appreciated..

thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do this with touchswipe.js if you want to use a library, if not you can track swipe distance with js by getting current position on touchstart and end position on touchend and doing your calculation then

Comment: I looked at the documentation and was a bit confused... could you show me an example of using touchswipe to move an object to left 150px... would help a lot... thanks